# SQL query to retrieve loan number, state, city, UPB and todays date

Tags: sql, getdate

I TRIED ANSWERING THIS QUESTION, HAVE A RESULT BUT I THINK THERE IS MORE TO IT.

Write a SQL query to retrieve loan number, state, city, UPB and today's date for loans in the state of TX that have a UPB greater than $100,000 or loans that are in the state of CA or FL that have a UPB greater than or equal to $500,000.

HERE IS MY CODE.YOUR OPINIONS PLEASE.

```
SELECT LoanNumber,State,City,UPB,GETDATE() TODAYSDATE 
FROM [dbo].[Loan]
WHERE UPB > 100000 
OR (State = 'CA'OR State = 'FL')
AND UPB >= 500000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LoanNumber,State, City,UPB, GETDATE() TODAYSDATE

FROM [dbo].[Loan]

WHERE (UPB > 100000 AND State = 'TX')

OR (State IN ('CA','FL') AND UPB >= 500000)
```

Is this what you need?